# How do I find table column in different databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find table columns in different tables and different databases.

So far, I do have a query to do that, however it does not tell me in which database that column and table lays in.

Current code:

```
SELECT
    sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
    tables.name AS TableName
FROM
    sys.columns
JOIN 
    sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
WHERE 
    sys.columns.name LIKE '%COLUMNNAME%'
```

Does anyone have an idea what I need to add to display the database name as well?

Comment: *"however it does not tell me in which database that column and Table lays in"* That query is run in the context of the current database; so it's whatever database you're currently connected to. It won't tell you the details of columns/tables in any other database, just the current database. If you can't remember what database you're connect to, use `DB_NAME()`.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. Could it be that some tables are hidden? I only got read access, and even though the above code tells me that the key i am looking for is in Table X, i cant find that table in the object explorer.

Comment: Perhaps the table has been created since you connected the to server and you haven't refreshed the object explorer?

Comment: I dont think that will be the case. I am a mediocre user of SQL and i just build queries for some analytical usage. I am not in charge of building the servers etc...

Comment: So, if you're not in charge of the objects, then wouldn't that mean that there well could have been an object since you connected that you're not aware of? If the query is telling you there's an object there, then you'll be able to see it in the Object Explorer, as it gets the list of objects from the `sys` objects when you first connect. Perhaps is on a different schema and you're looking in the wrong place; but not having refreshed the Object Exp[lorer is the very likely candidate in my opinion. I can only guess though; i can't see what you do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables` or `.columns` like:

```
SELECT table_name, table_schema, table_catalog 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
where Table_name like '%<table>%'
```

Same with `.columns`. Just replace `table_name` with `column_name`

```
SELECT column_name, table_schema, table_catalog, * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where column_name like '%<Column>%'
```

Comment: Be careful here. These views are a bit sketchy at best, they are there for backwards compatibility. The column table_schema is not accurate and MS even states that in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks,  I gave your query a go, but I still cant seem to find that table, although it tells me the database :/

Comment: @SeanLange I agree, with intricate DB's. The DB_Name() is good as well `SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS [Database], database_id  
FROM sys.databases`. Just providing alternate answers to the other(s)

Comment: @HansDampf I edited my post. If you're trying columns. Try the bottom version. It'll display column, table, catalog, etc.